# Visual Studio 2012 in profiling mode gives much better performance

Tags: silverlight, rest, visual-studio-2012, profiling

I have come across a strange situation and do not know what or how to look for.

We are having a Silverlight project hosted in a web project. This Silverlight project communicates using REST services hosted by the web project.

Now when we run this in debug mode, Everything runs fine as expected. So I thought of profiling it and checking which all places I might be loosing performance. So here is the interesting part.

I ran VS2012 Profiler and its is collecting all information related to methods executed, time and so on. But this time my project is lightning fast. Queries which used to take under normal debug about 1 sec to execute are now taking less than 200ms. There is one very intensive query which takes about 20 sec to execute in normal mode, but under profiling it takes less than 600ms.

So what I make out of this is that my code and project is capable of running this fast but for some reason it is not that fast under normal debug scenarios.

Can somebody throw light as what is happening under the hood and how can I achieve this performance in normal scenarios.

I would also like to mention that I have also tried release mode and publishing to IIS but none of these give as good performance as when in profiling mode.

Technically what I thought earlier is under profiling mode, performance should be less than normal as at that instant VS2012 is also collection other data.

I am confused. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know you probably don't need help at this point, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this post, I'll give my two cents.

I had this same problem with an XNA project I'm working on. Debug and Release modes both saw MASSIVE slowdowns in a certain situations. It pulled me down to less than 1 FPS. I was trying to profile the problem to solve it, but the issue never occurred during profiling.

I finally discovered the slowdowns were caused by a Console.WriteLine() I was calling in the situation. Commenting it out solved the issues on both Debug and Release build. Apparently, Console.WriteLine is just INCREDIBLY slow.